# I'm getting error "error: bad escape \d at position 1" when I'm trying to convert date format using regex and replace

Tags: python, regex, pandas, datetime, replace

I'm getting error "**error: bad escape \d at position 1**" when working on date formatting. I have to *convert* from format 11/13.2015 to 11/13/2015. I'm replacing using a regex and converting to a date-time format. Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
File = pd.read_excel("dotcharacter.xlsx")
Final_file = File["Date"].replace("[\d{2}\/\d{2}\.\d{4}]","[\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}]",regex=True)
Final_file["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(Final_file["Date"]).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
Final_file.to_excel("modified_file.xlsx")
```

Simple, `File.replace(".","/")` will do the trick. However, how can I  test using a regex? I'm new to Python. So, I am trying something different.

Comment: You need a double backslash. One to escape the backslash, and one to be a part of `\d`. So it's `\\d`.

Comment: Use a raw string for regular expressions.

Comment: Should I use \\d everywhere replacing \d - @Nick

Comment: Barmar's suggestion, of using a raw string, like `r'...'` is probably easier to read. But both ways will work.

Comment: @NickODell - Tried the code "Final_file = File.replace("[r"\d{2}\/\d{2}\.\d{4}"]","[r"\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}"]",regex=True)" but I'm getting new error "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character". I don't see space anywhere in the code. Please help.

Comment: `"[r"` This isn't the right way to make a raw string. The r goes before the quote. And another quote will end the raw string early.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I understood raw string representation is r'...' and r"...". But, it is not working in this case. I don't know why. Could you please, help me out?

Comment: Guys, can anyone please, help me on the below line of code. I'm getting error when I'm trying to execute:   `New_File = File.replace(r"\\d{2}\/\d{2}\.\d{4}",r"\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}",regex=True)`. Error is KeyError: '\\d' and error: bad escape \d at position 0